# directive from an ngModule imported in a standalone component does not function

Tags: angular

I literally just knew what standalone is in Angular, and I seem to be having trouble with it already. I'll divide the problem into 2 perspectives: User's perspective and developer's perspective.

User's perspective:

When the user hovers over a div box, it should change color. That's simply not happening.

Developer's Perspective:

The only directive in the small test application is not functioning at all.

Take a look at my following commented code.

App Module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ListComponent, // A standalone component
    NotStandaloneModule // is this supposed to be here?
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

NOT standalone module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HighlightDirective], // the directive that's not working
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
```

Directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onClick() {
    console.log("does this run?")
    this.highlight('yellow');
  }

   private highlight(color: string) {
    console.log("hellooooo??")
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

List TS Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NotStandaloneModule],
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
```

List Template:

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" appHighlight>    <!-- The appHighlight seems to have no affect on the DOM -->
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `appHighlight` does not work. Is it perhaps because I need to do anything in `NotStandaloneModule`? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Add directive into the export array of module. `exports:[appHighlightDirective]`